# NullPoinerException Linq max array

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a method that finds max and average from array of objects and returns it, but im getting NullPointerException at  b.Brzina and a.Brzina and Im not sure how to fix that.

```
string foo = metoda();
Console.WriteLine(foo);
Console.ReadKey();

static Auto[] niz = new Auto[3];

public static string metoda()
{
    var max = niz.Max(b => b.Brzina);
    double avg = niz.Average(a => a.Brzina);
    string autoo = "najbrzi auto je" + max.ToString() + "a prosecna brzina je" + avg.ToString();
    return autoo.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is `niz`? How do you populate it. There must be a null value in it that's why you are seeing this error.

Comment: Nis iz already populated in void main

Comment: Did you debug and check if it doesn't have any null item? What is the type of `Brzina` property? You need to debug and see if there is any item in the list is null or any it in the list with `Brzina` set to null.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gmcr7s It is null only at the point where it needs to calculate max

Comment: Remove `Auto[] niz  = new Auto[3];` from inside the main method.

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: Can you debug and check if `niz` is not null and all the items of it not null? Updating question with main may god would be helpful. Did you follow the answer marked as duplicate by Steve?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gmcy4m everything is populated in niz

Comment: You could just pass a reference into the function to avoid scope confusion: `public static string metoda(Auto[] niz)` and then call it from main by `string foo = metoda(niz);`